# With TikZ is it possible to pass the node content through a preprocessor?

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes

I've written a macro that scans its content for *illegal* characters and then changes them to something more *appropriate*.  In the following example, the macro scans for `_` and replaces them with `\rule[-1pt]{0.75em}{1.0pt}`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\makeatletter

\newcommand\aescandash[1]{%%
  \let\ae@scan@dash@result\relax
  \ae@scan@dash@parse#1_\@nil
  \ae@scan@dash@result
}

\def\ae@add@to@result#1#2{%%
  \ifx#1\relax
    \def#1{#2}%%
  \else
    \expandafter\def\expandafter#1\expandafter{#1#2}%%
  \fi}

\def\ae@scan@dash@parse#1_#2\@nil{%%
  \def\ae@reevaluate{}%%
  \expandafter\ifx\expandafter\relax\detokenize\expandafter{#2}\relax
    \ae@add@to@result\ae@scan@dash@result{#1}%%
  \else
    \ae@add@to@result\ae@scan@dash@result{#1\rule[-1pt]{0.75em}{1.0pt}}%%
    \def\ae@reevaluate{\ae@scan@dash@parse#2\@nil}%%
  \fi
  \ae@reevaluate
  }

\makeatother

\begin{document}

\aescandash{this_is_a_dash_filled_sentence}

\end{document}
```

I would like to be able to apply such a pre-processor to the content of nodes in a TikZ picture:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[%%
  my node/.style={red,
                  preprocessor=\aescandash},
  ]

  \foreach \myn [count=\myc from 1] in {this,that,another_text}
  {
    \node[my node] at (0,-\myc) {\myn};
  }

\end{tikzpicture}
```

But there is no such `preprocessor` key.  Ideally I would like the preprocessor to effectly pass to the node contents something along the lines of:

```
\expandafter\aescandash\expandafter{\myn}
```

In other words, the preprocessor would accomplish what the following code does:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[%%
  my node/.style={red},
  ]

  \foreach \myn [count=\myc from 1] in {this,that,another_text}
  {
    \node[my node] at (0,-\myc) {\expandafter\aescandash\expandafter{\myn}};
  }

\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: You're looking for disgrace. `;-)`

Comment: @egreg I'm not sure I understand.  Am I doing something foolish here?  Or asking for something so obvious?

Comment: If you don't want “dangerous input”, don't allow it to begin with. But printing an underscore as such is not really difficult.

Comment: @egreg Ah well that I get.  But I'm trying to document some code for in which such illegal characters are abundant.  But I've had other occasions where I wanted to preformat the content passed to a node (not necessarily to strip and replace characters).  Here it just seemed simple enough to create an understandable MWE.

Answer (score 7):

Why not just this?

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\makeatletter

\newcommand\aescandash[1]{%%
  \let\ae@scan@dash@result\relax
  \ae@scan@dash@parse#1_\@nil
  \ae@scan@dash@result
}

\def\ae@add@to@result#1#2{%%
  \ifx#1\relax
  \def#1{#2}%%
  \else
  \expandafter\def\expandafter#1\expandafter{#1#2}%%
  \fi}

\def\ae@scan@dash@parse#1_#2\@nil{%%
  \def\ae@reevaluate{}%%
  \expandafter\ifx\expandafter\relax\detokenize\expandafter{#2}\relax
  \ae@add@to@result\ae@scan@dash@result{#1}%%
  \else
  \ae@add@to@result\ae@scan@dash@result{#1\rule[-1pt]{0.75em}{1.0pt}}%%
  \def\ae@reevaluate{\ae@scan@dash@parse#2\@nil}%%
  \fi
  \ae@reevaluate
}

\makeatother

\begin{document}

  \begin{tikzpicture}
    [
      my node/.code={
        \let\oldmyn\myn
        \gdef\myn{\expandafter\aescandash\expandafter{\oldmyn}}%
      },
    ]

    \foreach \myn [count=\myc from 1] in {this,that,another_text}
    {
      \node[my node] at (0,-\myc) {\myn};
    }

  \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: my node code]

Comment: This is not quite what I want, but it does suggest a solution that will work for my immediate purposes.

Answer (score 5):

It is possible to insert a preprocessor, but obviously this involves a teensy hack of the node parser.

In the code below I define a `preprocess node content` key which takes a macro as an argument. This macro should be defined to take one argument, which will be the text to process. Obviously if there is something more complex than simple text then the whole thing may fail miserably.

I also show an alternative (although not necessarily better) way of replacing characters using extended latex. I use asterisks instead of underscores so no errors result when there is no preprocessor.

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=5]{standalone}

\makeatletter    
\let\tikz@do@fig@original=\tikz@do@fig
\newtoks\tikz@fig@toks%
\def\tikz@do@fig@preprocessed{%
  \tikz@do@fig@original%
  \afterassignment\tikz@do@fig@@preprocessed%
  \tikz@fig@toks=\bgroup}

\def\tikz@do@fig@@preprocessed{%
  \expandafter\tikz@fig@preprocess\expandafter{\the\tikz@fig@toks}%
  \egroup}

\def\tikz@fig@preprocess#1{#1}
\tikzset{%
  preprocess node content/.code={%
    \let\tikz@fig@preprocess=#1\relax%
    \let\tikz@do@fig=\tikz@do@fig@preprocessed%
  }
}
\makeatother

{\catcode`\*=13 \gdef*{\rule[-1pt]{0.75em}{1.0pt}}}
\def\pp#1{{\catcode`\*=13 \scantokens{#1\ignorespaces}}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node [draw] at (0,0) {*foo*bar*};
\node [draw, preprocess node content=\pp] at (0,-1) {*foo*bar*};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: So is `\tikz@do@fig` the macro that TikZ uses to store the node contents?

Comment: I like your approach for handling characters better than my recursive approach:  it seems more natural.

Comment: @A.Ellett essentially yes, but it is a bit more complex. `\tikz@do@fig` (in older versions it was `\tikz@@fig@main`) is executed after the open `{` of the node contents is stripped away. All the options for node contents are executed and then an `\hbox` is started which collects the node contents up the closing `}`. So in the normal course of events TikZ only knows about the box rather than its contents.

Answer (score 3):

There is actually a preprocessor in disguise. You can use the `node contents` key started with TikZ 3. And via style nesting it becomes a preprocessor. But the downside is that you have to give all the specs within the brackets because closing bracket finishes the node parsing on a path.

**Edit**: After cfr's correction, a little better with the option to choose a preprocessor or turn it off. `scanned node contents` is admittedly a bloated name so you can choose something more catchy.

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\makeatletter
\newcommand\aescandash[1]{\let\ae@scan@dash@result\relax\ae@scan@dash@parse#1_\@nil\ae@scan@dash@result}
\def\ae@add@to@result#1#2{\ifx#1\relax\def#1{#2}\else\expandafter\def\expandafter#1\expandafter{#1#2}\fi}

\def\ae@scan@dash@parse#1_#2\@nil{\def\ae@reevaluate{}%
\expandafter\ifx\expandafter\relax\detokenize\expandafter{#2}\relax%
    \ae@add@to@result\ae@scan@dash@result{#1}%%
  \else\ae@add@to@result\ae@scan@dash@result{#1\rule[-1pt]{0.75em}{1.0pt}}%
\def\ae@reevaluate{\ae@scan@dash@parse#2\@nil}%%
  \fi%
  \ae@reevaluate%
  }
\makeatother

\tikzset{
  preprocessor/.store in=\mypreproc,
  preprocessor=aescandash,
  %preprocessor=, % Turn it off
  scanned node contents/.style={
    node contents={\csname\mypreproc\endcsname{#1}},
  }
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[scanned node contents={this_is_a_dash_filled_sentence},fill=red!10,at={(1,0)},anchor=west];
\node[scanned node contents={another_dashed_one},fill=blue!10,at={(0,1)}];
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: (+1) but it doesn't use the requested syntax...

Comment: @cfr Uh oh, completely missed that spec.

Comment: It is more preprocessor like, though.

Comment: Very nice.  In spirit, it looks very much like what I came up with from @cfr 's solution.

Comment: Is TikZ 3 availabel through a LaTeX update or do I have to go through CVS?

Comment: @A.Ellett Version on CTAN/in TeX Live is 3. Don't know about MiKTeX. I think that might have an older version, but I'm not sure.

Comment: While my question appears to request a `preprocessor` key, your solution would suggest that's unnecessary baggage given that I could write `scanned node contents/.style={node content={\expandafter\aescandash\expandafter{\myn}}}`.  (I use `\expandafter` here only because in my example above I'd be passing `\myn` to this key.

Comment: @A.Ellett True but if you want to change the preprocessor then you need to type the whole key. So you can change along the way

Comment: Why does `at={(0,1)}` have to go in the optional argument to `\node`?  I tried using your code but written more like `\node[node contents={this is scanned}] at (0,1);` and get an error about `\@next` not matching its definition.

Comment: @A.Ellett when used, `node contents` finishes the node parsing after closing bracket and doesn't understand the rest

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to @cfr , this is the solution I came up with.  I didn't fully go with his solution because I need `\myn` unaltered for later purposes in my main document.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\makeatletter

\newcommand\aescandash[1]{%%
  \let\ae@scan@dash@result\relax
  \ae@scan@dash@parse#1_\@nil
  \ae@scan@dash@result
}

\def\ae@add@to@result#1#2{%%
  \ifx#1\relax
    \def#1{#2}%%
  \else
    \expandafter\def\expandafter#1\expandafter{#1#2}%%
  \fi}

\def\ae@scan@dash@parse#1_#2\@nil{%%
  \def\ae@reevaluate{}%%
  \expandafter\ifx\expandafter\relax\detokenize\expandafter{#2}\relax
    \ae@add@to@result\ae@scan@dash@result{#1}%%
  \else
    \ae@add@to@result\ae@scan@dash@result{#1\rule[-1pt]{0.75em}{1.0pt}}%%
    \def\ae@reevaluate{\ae@scan@dash@parse#2\@nil}%%
  \fi
  \ae@reevaluate
  }

\makeatother

\begin{document}

\aescandash{this_is_a_dash_filled_sentence}

\begin{tikzpicture}[%%
  my node/.style={red},
  my node content/.code={\def\aenodecontent{\expandafter\aescandash\expandafter{#1}}},
  ]

  \foreach \myn [count=\myc from 1] in {this,that,another_text}
  {
    \node[my node,my node content=\myn] at (0,-\myc) {\aenodecontent};
  }

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Instead of upvoting this solution, please upvote cfr's solution (hence the reason for making this community wiki).  But I felt what I wound up doing was just different enough to warrant posting the approach I took.

Comment: (+1) I would change `node content` to `my node content` to avoid confusion with `node contents`. (Obviously not a technical objection since a computer wouldn't confuse them. But humans would. At least, this human would.)