# Could someone further elucidate expansion, catcodes, and scantokens...?

Tags: expansion, e-tex

In response to my question "[With TikZ is it possible to pass the node content through a preprocessor?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/213581/22413)", @MarkWibrow suggested a solution using `\scantokens`.

```
{\catcode`\_=13 \gdef_{\rule[-1pt]{0.75em}{1.0pt}}}
\def\pp#1{{\catcode`\_=13 \scantokens{#1\ignorespaces}}}
```

I've never understood why `\scantokens` would be useful or not, and I've seen plenty of warnings about the reputed dangers of `\scantokens`.  The documentation in `e-TeX` is rather sparse (at least, too sparse to enlighten me at all).  So, I decided to experiment a bit on my own and wrote my own version of `\pp`:

```
\def\aepp#1{{\catcode`\_=13 #1}}
```

But

```
 \aepp{hello_world}
```

results in an error

```
! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text> 
                $
```

I thought, initially, that I perhaps didn't understand something about how `\catcode` works and tried the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
{\catcode`\_=13 \gdef_{\rule[-1pt]{0.75em}{1.0pt}}}
\setlength\parindent{0pt}
\begin{document}
{\catcode`\_=13 hello_world}
\end{document}
```

which compiles without error.

I find this a bit confusing, because isn't

```
{\catcode`\_=13 hello_world}
```

what `\aepp{hello_world}`  expands to?

So, while I'm quite a bit in the dark about `\scantokens`, I'm more curious about why expansion of `\aepp{hello_world}` failed to accomplish what `\pp{hello_world}` does.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

TeX's scanner (eyes) convert *characters* in a file to *tokens*. That only happens once, macro replacement text and all expansion processing processes tokens (which are [character-code,catcode] pairs.

the catcode table affects the conversion of characters to character tokens.

So your definition locally makes the catcode of `_` 13 so if a `_` *character* is encounted in that scope it would tokenize as a `(_,13)` token. But you pass it a token list as `#1` of tokens that have already been tokenized so the catcode table is never consulted, so your change to the table is not used.

`\scantokens` acts as if the tokens are written to a file producing a stream of *characters* which are then read back so retokenised using the current catcode table.

Without `\scantokens` the classic construct you are looking for is:

```
\documentclass{article}
{\catcode`\_=13 \gdef_{\rule[-1pt]{0.75em}{1.0pt}}}
\setlength\parindent{0pt}
\begin{document}
{\catcode`\_=13 hello_world}

\def\aepp{\bgroup\catcode`\_=13 \xaepp}
\def\xaepp#1{#1\egroup}
\aepp{hello_world}


\end{document}
```

which changes the catcode of `_` before the argument is read. But this (like `\verb` not coincidentally) does not work if nested in the argument of another command, as then again the argument has already been tokenised.

Comment: Thank you for the example of `\xaepp`:  it made me think about this a bit more to understand how it worked around scanning tokens too early.

Comment: Will the future bring us a `\verb` that works inside arguments (by “actively changing catcodes” with `\scantokes`). Or is there a problem?

Comment: @Manuel there's always a problem:-) `\verb|   |` is supposed to make three spaces but `\scantokens{   }` only makes one, unless you have already changed the catcode of space but if you've done that you don't need scantokens. (There are other problems but handling various white space issues are probably the hardest)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I guess, since it's inline code, that spaces don't count too much. That's not a big deal.

Comment: @Manuel well it's easy for you to say that as you wouldn't be on the receiving end of the email bug reports if `\verb` became `\verb-apart-from-space-and-#-and-%-and-{and-}` :-) (which by the way is more or less `\verb` in `tabularx` which uses `\meaning` rather than `\scantokens` but has similar behaviour)

Answer (score 20):

The `\scantokens` command is not “dangerous” by itself, but it can have surprising effects.

How does it work? Its argument is scanned like for a `\write` operation, but all symbolic tokens are considered unexpandable, based on the current category codes; the result is placed in a “pseudofile” that is read in exactly as if `\input` was used.

This has various consequences; for instance an implicit space token is added at the end, actually an end-of-line character, exactly like TeX does with `\input`. This space can be neutralized in various ways, but the most common one is adding `\empty` or `\noexpand` at the end of the token list for `\scantokens`. Using `\ignorespaces` is not in my list of recommendations:

```
\scantokens{a\ignorespaces}X\scantokens{a\empty}X

\scantokens{a\ignorespaces} X\scantokens{a\empty} X
```

will output

[image]

so you see the effect of `\ignorespaces` goes beyond `\scantokens`.

One might be tempted to use `\scantokens` for getting verbatim in the argument to a command, but there's a catch:

```
\def\test#1{\begingroup\tt\catcode`\\=12
  \scantokens{#1}\endgroup}

\test{\abc\def}
```

will output

[image]

(I'm using Plain TeX for simplicity). Where does the space come from? In the internal representation for `\write`, control words are followed by a space; the change in category code for the backslash happens too late.

Another (admittedtly tricky) quirk:

```
\def\test#1{\begingroup\tt\catcode`\\=12
  \scantokens{#1}\endgroup}
\newlinechar`^^J

\test{a^^Jb^^J^^Jc}
```

will make TeX read the pseudofile as if it were

```
a
b

c
```

but the result is *not*

> `a b\par c`

as it could be expected; rather, it is

[image]

because TeX converts the two consecutive end-of-lines into *the token* `\par`, not into the control sequence `\par`. This is proved by

```
\def\test#1{\begingroup\tt\catcode`\\=12 \edef\par{\string\par}%
  \scantokens{#1}\endgroup}
\newlinechar`^^J

\test{a^^Jb^^J^^Jc}
```

that outputs

[image]

Exercise: explain the details.

Final quirk: one can use `\scantokens\expandafter{\foo}` and `\foo` will be expanded before `\scantokens` does its job:

```
\def\test#1{\begingroup\tt\catcode`\\=12
  \scantokens\expandafter{#1}\endgroup}

\def\foo{\abc\def}

\test\foo

\bye
```

will do the same as before

[image: previous image]

In order to have `\scantokens` inside `\edef`, one needs one more trick: the end-of-file must be hidden.

```
\def\escantokens#1#2#3{%
  \begingroup\everyeof{\noexpand}%
  #3%
  \edef\x{\endgroup\def\noexpand#1{\scantokens{#2}}}\x
}

\escantokens\demo{\abc\def}{\catcode`\\=12 }\show\demo

\escantokens\demo{\abc}{\def\abc{ABC}}\show\demo

\bye
```

The third argument to `\escantokens` is a set of temporary assignments (category codes, for instance, but not only).

The output on the terminal is

```
> \demo=macro:
->\abc \def .
l.8 \show\demo

? 
> \demo=macro:
->ABC.
l.10 ...tokens\demo{\abc}{\def\abc{ABC}}\show\demo

?
```

Comment: Regarding `\ignorespaces`, I noticed that approach posted in several places on this site, but when I tried `\edef\demo{\scantokens{foo\ignorespaces}}` I got an error of `File ended while scanning definition of \demo.`  What's going on here?

Comment: @A.Ellett `\scantokens` inside `\edef` opens a new can of worms!

Comment: @A.Ellett I added it