# Unwanted extra space after hyperlink with biblatex

Tags: spacing, biblatex, hyperref

I am using `biblatex` for my references, and I found the `chem-angew` style which I appreciate very much.

I found out how to add an hypertext link under the journal title, and it works fine. 
But there is one slight problem: I do not know how to remove the extra space caused by the hypertext link (if I remove the hyperlink, the extra space disappears).
Note that if the link is followed by a comma, there is no problem... But in the `chem-angew` style, there is no comma between the journal title and the year. And I want the hypertext link to be under the journal title.

Does anyone know what to do?
Do I have to define completely my own `biblatex` style?

Here is my code:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[backend=biber,
        style=chem-angew,
        firstinits=true,
        maxbibnames=99]{biblatex}
\renewbibmacro{in:}{}
\addbibresource{library2.bib}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{urlcolor=black, colorlinks=true}

%*************Hyperlink on title****************
\newbibmacro{string+doiurlisbn}[1]{%
  \iffieldundef{doi}{%
    \iffieldundef{url}{%
      \iffieldundef{isbn}{%
        \iffieldundef{issn}{%
          #1%
         }{%
          \href{http://books.google.com/books?vid=ISSN\thefield{issn}}{#1}%
        }%
      }{%
        \href{http://books.google.com/books?vid=ISBN\thefield{isbn}}{#1}%
      }%
     }{%
      \href{\thefield{url}}{#1}%
    }%
  }{%
    \href{http://dx.doi.org/\thefield{doi}}{#1}%
  }%
}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{journaltitle}%
    {\usebibmacro{string+doiurlisbn}% 
    {\mkbibemph{#1}}%
    }
\DeclareFieldFormat[manual]{title}%
    {\usebibmacro{string+doiurlisbn} 
    {\mkbibemph{#1}}
    }
\begin{document}
I really wonder why there is an extra space in the bibliography \cite{Bocquet2010}!
I wish I could erase it \cite{Nicholls2012}. 
However, it depends on what type of document you cite \cite{Palacci2010}.
\label{Bibliography}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

And here is the `.bib`:

```
@article{Bocquet2010,
author = {Bocquet, Lyd\'{e}ric and Charlaix, Elisabeth},
doi = {10.1039/B909366B},
journal = {Chemical Society Reviews},
number = {3},
pages = {1073--1095},
title = {{Nanofluidics, from bulk to interfaces.}},
url = {http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/20179826},
volume = {39},
year = {2010}
}
@article{Nicholls2012,
author = {Nicholls, William D. and Borg, Matthew K. and Lockerby, Duncan A. and Reese, Jason M.},
doi = {10.1007/s10404-011-0869-3},
journal = {Microfluidics and Nanofluidics},
number = {1-4},
pages = {257--264},
title = {{Water transport through (7,7) carbon nanotubes of different lengths using molecular dynamics}},
url = {http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/s10404-011-0869-3},
volume = {12},
year = {2012}
}
@manual{Palacci2010,
author = {Palacci, J\'{e}r\'{e}mie},
organization = {Universit\'{e} Claude-Bernard},
title = {{Manipulation of colloids by osmotic forces}},
url = {https://tel.archives-ouvertes.fr/tel-00597477/fr/},
type = {phdthesis},
urldate = {09-22-2015},
location = {Lyon, France},
year = {2010}
}
```

And finally here is what I get with this code:
[image]

Thanks a lot to whom may take some time to answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Joseph Wright has just fixed [the issue](https://github.com/josephwright/biblatex-chem/issues/10) properly.

---

This is due to the special field format `removecomma` used in `\renewbibmacro*{journal}` and defined as `\DeclareFieldFormat{removecomma}{\mkbibnocomma{#1}}`.

Specifically, the space is introduced by the `\scantokens` command in

```
\newcommand*\mkbibnocomma[1]{%
  \begingroup
    \catcode`\, = 9\relax
    \scantokens{#1}%
  \endgroup
}
```

Refer also to [@egreg's answer to *Could someone further elucidate expansion, catcodes, and scantokens…?*](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/213713/35864)

Normally that space is eaten up by `\unspace`s that are issued by the punctuation commands, but once the space is inside the hyperref command it seems to late.

A temporary redefinition is

```
\renewcommand*\mkbibnocomma[1]{%
  \begingroup
    \catcode`\, = 9\relax
    \scantokens{#1\empty}%
  \endgroup
}
```

We get the correct output.

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage[backend=biber,
        style=chem-angew,
        firstinits=true,
        maxbibnames=99]{biblatex}
\renewbibmacro{in:}{}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@article{Bocquet2010,
author = {Bocquet, Lyd\'{e}ric and Charlaix, Elisabeth},
doi = {10.1039/B909366B},
journal = {Chemical Society Reviews},
number = {3},
pages = {1073--1095},
title = {{Nanofluidics, from bulk to interfaces.}},
url = {http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/20179826},
volume = {39},
year = {2010}
}
@article{Nicholls2012,
author = {Nicholls, William D. and Borg, Matthew K. and Lockerby, Duncan A. and Reese, Jason M.},
doi = {10.1007/s10404-011-0869-3},
journal = {Microfluidics and Nanofluidics},
number = {1-4},
pages = {257--264},
title = {{Water transport through (7,7) carbon nanotubes of different lengths using molecular dynamics}},
url = {http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/s10404-011-0869-3},
volume = {12},
year = {2012}
}
@manual{Palacci2010,
author = {Palacci, J\'{e}r\'{e}mie},
organization = {Universit\'{e} Claude-Bernard},
title = {{Manipulation of colloids by osmotic forces}},
url = {https://tel.archives-ouvertes.fr/tel-00597477/fr/},
type = {phdthesis},
urldate = {2015-09-22},
location = {Lyon, France},
year = {2010}
}
\end{filecontents*}


\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\usepackage{hyperref}

%*************Hyperlink on title****************
\newbibmacro{string+doiurlisbn}[1]{%
  \iffieldundef{doi}{%
    \iffieldundef{url}{%
      \iffieldundef{isbn}{%
        \iffieldundef{issn}{%
          #1%
         }{%
          \href{http://books.google.com/books?vid=ISSN\thefield{issn}}{#1}%
        }%
      }{%
        \href{http://books.google.com/books?vid=ISBN\thefield{isbn}}{#1}%
      }%
     }{%
      \href{\thefield{url}}{#1}%
    }%
  }{%
    \href{http://dx.doi.org/\thefield{doi}}{#1}%
  }%
}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{journaltitle}%
    {\usebibmacro{string+doiurlisbn}% 
    {\mkbibemph{#1}}}
\DeclareFieldFormat[manual]{title}%
    {\usebibmacro{string+doiurlisbn} 
    {\mkbibemph{#1}}}

\renewcommand*\mkbibnocomma[1]{%
  \begingroup
    \catcode`\, = 9\relax
    \scantokens{#1\empty}%
  \endgroup
}

\begin{document}
I really wonder why there is an extra space in the bibliography \cite{Bocquet2010}!
I wish I could erase it \cite{Nicholls2012}. 
However, it depends on what type of document you cite \cite{Palacci2010}.
\label{Bibliography}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: Don't know who you are moewe but you totally rock !
Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Catherine Glad I could be of help. If that answer solved your problem, you might want to consider accepting it using the green checkmark and up-voting it.